# Common Travel Area - No UK Visa

Tags: ireland, northern-ireland, common-travel-area

So just something I've been wondering...

If someone is granted entry to ROI but has no UK visa, are they allowed to travel to NI due to the CTA? I have a Bolivian friend wanting to travel and he can enter ROI without a visa, just an outward ticket, but he wants to visit NI while there. I know that he *could* just drive up and most likely no-one would even notice, but my question is would that actually be legal? I don't understand the CTA at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If he doesn’t have a return ticket he could be refused entry to ROI

Comment: @Traveller while that is true, it's also worth noting a return ticket is not strictly required.  There are also many other conditions that "could" lead to refusal.

Answer (score 3):

The UK's guidance on the [British-Irish Visa Scheme](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme) has this to say (about people who aren't eligible for BIVS):

> If a national of a country requires a visa for the UK but not for Ireland, those nationals will still require a visit visa to travel to the UK. The same will apply to any nationals who are not required to have a visa to visit the UK but are required to have one for Ireland.

This describes the current situation in law.

So far only nationals of India and China can receive BIVS visas. Everyone else must apply for the visas separately as described there.